# Column 'Comments.Text' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: azure-sql-database, aggregate, group-by

This question: [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/) have explained the root of the problem very well and even advised to use max aggregate as [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13999903/1083704). But, lets take the example

```
group_id    item_id     comment
--------------------------------
1       abc     "blah-blah"
1       def     "tral-la-lah"
1       ghi
2       jkl
2       mno
2       pqr
```

I understand the solution: I must take an item to represent the group by `max(item_id)`. But how do I take the comment of the selected item? How does it help me to take the corresponding comment?

**edit**

Everything is like in this question: [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/). The only complication that I address here is the extra `comment` column that I want to select along with the `max(item_id) group by group_id`.

I am using this beast, [Which tools and technologies are used to build Data Explorer? | Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52063/201017)

Comment: Please show us your SQL query and the definition of the involved table(s).

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear, but I think you want something like this:

```
select group_id, 
       item_id, 
       comment
from (
   select group_id,
          item_id, 
          comment, 
          row_number() over (partition by group_id order by item_id) as rn
   from the_unknown_table
) t
where rn = 1;
```

(you didn't state your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL)

SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a8471/1

Comment: Sorry, I wanted a select grouped by group_id.

Comment: @Val: that's what my query does (only a minor typo: `goup` instead of `group_id`)

Comment: Amazing. But what is the rn = 1?

Comment: @Val: it's a window function that essentially does a group by "on-the-fly". See e.g. here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Does `order by item_id` change anything if I replace it with `order by group_id`?

Comment: @Val: yes it will. As each "partition" is done already by the `group_id` the order by wouldn't achieve anything. You need  it to pick the "first" value of the item_id, otherwise you don't get a consistent result.

Comment: So, I could not understand whether `order by` has any effect or not. But, it does not matter which row do you pick. This is the meaning of equivalence of items within the partition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Partitions_and_equivalence_relations!